# Does spring-data-redis support redis clusters?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

Does spring-data-redis support redis clusters?

Any example will be helpful for me.

Comment: It is the very same question that I have in mind while searching for a solution for Redis cluster / Spring Data. Wondering why this question closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data Redis [delegates the Redis connection to a driver library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:connectors), and [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) does support clustering. (JRedis is also supported by SDR, but the project appears to have been discontinued as of 2011.)

Sentinels are supported, but only with Jedis.