# Does spring-data-redis automatically follow the key to the next node if it is not present in the current node?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

In relation to [Does spring-data-redis support redis clusters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031411/does-spring-data-redis-support-redis-clusters)

If I do a `SCAN` or `GET` for a key and the key is in another node, would Spring Data Redis (with Jedis driver) know to go to the other node to pick up the data or do I have to handle that scenario manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would Spring Data Redis (with Jedis driver) know to go to the other node to pick up the data

Yes.